# Remove class from buttons on changing values in editable div for dynamically generated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I am creating an app using knockout and jquery. There are user generated contents which a user can edit and save. I have a ***save button*** which is disabled and gets enabled only when new character is added to the editable div.

**Problem:**
Save button gets activated for all divs. I want only the respective button to get enabled and remaining should stay in disabled state.

**HTML:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.goals">
<div class="ui padded segment mainCard brdR-S" data-bind="attr:{id:Title()}">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div contenteditable="true" class="heading pdM-TB wordwrap" data-bind="attr:{href:'#'+Title()}, editableText: Title, event: { keyup: $root.ShowButtons }" id="goalTitle">
            </div>
            <div class="mgXl-T pdM-TB">
                <button class="ui disabled tiny primary button" id="btnSave" data-bind="click: $root.putGoal">
                    <i class="refresh icon"></i>Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    self.ShowButtons = function (data, e) {
    $('.button').removeClass('disabled')
};
```

Comment: One problem is that you are calling anything with the button class. Firstly ID should be unique, so using btnSave and goalTitle for ID isn't a good idea. Try to use some dynamic data for the ID. Then it will be much easier to call the specific button you want

Comment: There is missing code in your question: how does the model look like? how is the `editableText` binding implemented? Apart from this, you're mixing `ko` with `jQuery` DOM manipulation, which is a bad idea. You should do ti all using only `ko`, which is possible and easy to do. Please, improve your question by creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Look at these bindings: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/disable-binding.html
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html
and don't manipulate the DOM directly in your viewmodel code.